# EdgesHelper as child of a Cube get double rotation speed

Tags: three.js, rotation

When I add an EdgesHelper of a cube to the scene, then rotate the cube, the EdgesHelper follows the rotation.

But if I add EdgesHelper as child of cube, it rotates at **double** speed.

https://jsfiddle.net/aj3cv4tx/4/ +49

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, mesh );
var egh = new THREE.EdgesHelper( cube, 0x00ffff );

cube.add(egh);  // causes different ratation speed
//scene.add(egh);   // this one is ok
```

How can I fix its rotation speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is a consequence of how `EdgesHelper` (and some of the other helpers) have been implemented.

If you want to use `EdgesHelper`, you have to adhere to two rules:

1. `EdgesHelper` must be added to the scene, directly.
2. The scene can't have a transform applied (for example, be rotated).

three.js r.74

Comment: Thanks.  I just saw this line in EdgesHelper.js : `this.matrix = object.matrixWorld;`